# NSUserDefaults value customerID returns nil in iOS 11 Devices only on all API calls of my Project

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, socket.io, nsuserdefaults

I have been experiencing a weird issue on iOS11 Devices only. 
My Project built with socket.io API calls worked fine on any devices and even in iOS 11. From this Sunday All of the API Calls that contain customerid (userDefault Key) is returning nil and it causes all the API that sends customerid along with other keys generating following json error message in all iOS 11 devices. "Mandotary Field is Missing". 
P.S - This issue causing across all of my old backups that have worked well before and this issue, not affected any of iOS 10 or below devices.
Please check screen shot of following 2 versions.
[image: iOS 11 - Build 1.0]
[image: iOS - 10 - Build 1.0]

Following are some code snippet related to customerid contained API.

This is how storing the user defaults to use on other api when signing in.

```
     else  if (errFlag == 0 && requestType == RequestTypeSignIn)
        {
            // Save information
            NSUserDefaults *ud = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

            [ud setObject:flStrForStr(response[@"CustId"]) forKey:iServeCustomerID];
            [ud setObject:flStrForStr(response[@"fname"]) forKey:iServeUserFirstName];
            [ud setObject:flStrForStr(response[@"lname"]) forKey:iServeUserLastName];
            [ud setObject:flStrForStr(response[@"token"]) forKey:iServeCheckUserSessionToken];
            [ud setObject:flStrForStr(response[@"apiKey"]) forKey:iServeAPIKey];
            [ud setObject:flStrForStr(response[@"coupon"]) forKey:iServeCouponkey];
            [ud setObject:flStrForStr(response[@"email"])  forKey:iServeUserEmail];
            [ud setObject:self.passwordTextField.text forKey:iServeUserPassword];
            [ud setObject:flStrForStr(response[@"currency"]) forKey:iServeCurrentCountryCurrencySymbol];
            [ud setObject:flStrForStr(response[@"profilePic"]) forKey:iServeUserProfilepic];
            NSString *custIDD = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:iServeCustomerID];
            NSLog(@"CUSTIDD CUSTIDD%@", custIDD);
            if(response[@"stripe_pub_key"])
            {
                [ud setObject:response[@"stripe_pub_key"] forKey:iServeStripeKey];
                [Stripe setDefaultPublishableKey:response[@"stripe_pub_key"]];
            }

This is how passing customer id as userdefaults to get data from an api 

-(void)sendRequestToSaveAddress
{
    [[ProgressIndicator sharedInstance] showPIOnWindow:[UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow withMessage:NSLocalizedString(@"Saving...", @"Saving...")];

    PMDReachabilityWrapper *reachability = [PMDReachabilityWrapper sharedInstance];
    if([reachability isNetworkAvailable])
    {


        NSDictionary *params = @{
                                 kTWTSessionTokenkey:flStrForStr([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]objectForKey:iServeCheckUserSessionToken]),
                                 kTWTDeviceId:flStrForStr([Utilities getDeviceId]),
                                 @"ent_cust_id":[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:iServeCustomerID],
                                 @"ent_latitude":self.selectedAddressDetails[@"lat"],
                                 @"ent_longitude":self.selectedAddressDetails[@"log"],
                                 @"ent_address1":flStrForObj(self.selectedAddressTextView.text),
                                 @"ent_suite_num":flStrForObj(self.flatNumberTextField.text),
                                 @"ent_tag_address":selectedTagAddress,
                               };

        [[WebServiceHandler sharedInstance]sendRequestToAddAddress:params andDelegate:self];

    }
    else
    {
        [[ProgressIndicator sharedInstance]hideProgressIndicator];
        [UIHelper showMessage:iServeNetworkErrormessage withTitle:LS(@"oops!")delegate:self];
    }

}
```

Please Help me to fix this issue. I don't have any idea so far which caused this issue suddenly which worked perfectly in ios 11 for sometimes. Thank You.

Comment: Try using `[ud synchronize]` after setting all the values.

Comment: @Torongo Thanks. I missed the synchronization.